# Sending email through c# windows forms appication

Tags: c#

I can't send the email through c# when i press send email button it will stuck my code is this

```
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            message.From = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("example@gmail.com"));
            message.Subject = "Subject";
            message.Body = "Body";
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 465;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
            smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: [is not working](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2014/10/missing-stackoverflow-topic-terrible-question/)

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Nothing it just stucking

Comment: @MakhmoorRehman Are you catching any exception as shown in my sample. Putting breakpoint there can reveal what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong port for SMTP at Gmail, the correct port number is 587. Also , I recommend you to use Using Statement for `SmtpClient` as it implements `IDisposable` interface.

Even after changing port to the correct one, you may still face an exception as Gmail uses SSL for authentication. You will need to add remote server validation. It can be done using [`RemoteCertificateValidationCallback Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.100).aspx) which verifies the remote Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate used for authentication.

Here is the working code sample:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();          
message.From = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("example@gmail.com"));
message.Subject = "Subject";
message.Body = "Body";

try
{
  using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
  {
      smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
      smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                        delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                        {
                            return true;
                        };

      smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
      smtpClient.Send(emailMessage);
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
      emailMessage = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! for your helping guyz the code was right but in my account lesssecureapps was turned off when i turned it on my code will works anyways thanks to you all (Y)